# Macro output explanation

Tags: c

When I run the following code,

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define X (4+Y)
#define Y (X+3)

int main()
{
  printf("%d",4*X+2); 
  return 0;
}

I am getting the following output: 
Error: Undefined symbol 'X'
```

Can someone please explain the output?

Comment: There's a difference between variable-like macros and function-like macros. And what do you mean by "macro output"?

Comment: The code as presented should not even compile, let alone "run": `delete_me.c:2:11: error: "4" may not appear in macro parameter list
delete_me.c:3:12: error: "+" may not appear in macro parameter list`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is because the macro expects and argument since its defined with parentheses.
You would need to define it as

`#define X 4+Y` and `#define Y X+3`. Then you would run into another trouble because of cyclic definition in macros.

To be even more correct, as Drew suggested; when the example would be compilable when defining macros one usually puts the parentheses around expression to ensure expected operator precedence.

So your best shot would be:

```
#define X (4+Y)
#define Y (X+3)
```

Very close to your initial example, just a space character between name of a macro and its definition. **However, it is still impossible to properly expand the macro due to the cyclic reference.**

**How to check what happened:**

You can use `gcc -E`, which outputs a pre-processed file. It generates lots of output so  I used `tail`. I also used `2>err` to redirect error stream to a file, so the output is clear.

```
luk32:~/projects/tests$ gcc -E ./cyclic_macro_with_no_spaces.c 2> err | tail -n 6

int main()
{
  printf("%d",4*X+2);
  return 0;
}


luk32:~/projects/tests$ gcc -E ./cyclic_macro.c 2> err | tail -n 6

int main()
{
  printf("%d",4*(4+(X+3))+2);
  return 0;
}
```

In 1st example the `X` did not expand at all. While in the latter both macros got expanded, although only one. Giving the same output that Geoffrey presented in his answer.

Whether no space is a typo or not there is an `undefined symbol 'X'`. For different reason that are possible to trace by analyzing `err` files.

Comment: I am sorry. I had missed the spaces earlier. Have corrected the same. What I infer from your answer is that a macro is substituted for only
once. But consider the following case:
#define X (4+Z)

#define Z 2

int main()
{
printf("%d",X);
}

now according to you, the macro expands to 4+Z and should not substitute further and should also give error. But it works fine on my compiler. How would you explain this?

Comment: @user No. No. Each macro got expanded once, like Geoffrey said. `X` into (4+Y), and then from (4+**Y**) into (4+**(X+3)**). But the preprocessor stopped not dealing with `X` second time. With the `Z` example it would expand  `X` into (4+**Z**) and then (4+**2**). Each macro in the sence that during preprocessing a macro symbol, if preprocessor encounters the same symbol again it will not attempt a recursive substitution. I am no expert, so I do not know for sure. I am just analyzing the observed behaviour. Also I might have used improper terms. But the idea is clear.

Answer (score 5):

If the macros are left as invalid function-like macros, they are not getting expanded at all because you did not call it with parentheses. So X is never replaced with anything by the pre-processor, and is the reason for the `Undefined symbol 'X'` in your sample code.

If you wanted this to be expanded you would have to call it with parentheses like this:

```
printf("%d",4*X()+2);
```

This though would just error out when pre-processed as `4+Y` and `X+3` are not valid macro parameter names.

If your answer is corrected somewhat so that those defines are proper defines, and not function-like macros, ie:

```
#define X (4+Y)
#define Y (X+3)
```

You have a circular reference between the defines...

X -> Y -> X... etc.

Since it will only expand the macro once, it is getting expanded to

```
printf("%d",4*(4+(X+3))+2);
```

This explains why X is the undefined symbol in this use case.

Comment: Lack of space does not have to be a typo. `clang` and `gcc` will both report `undefined symbol 'X'` along the lines in either case. I think OP did not post full error message. However, in case original code had no spaces both tested compilers would suggest there is something wrong with the macro definition, while with spaces they dont. In the latter case they just report `undefined symbol` alone. So you might have been correct about the typo. I find it very probable. We can't be sure unless we see whole message and/or know the compiler used.

Comment: @luk32 - You posted that as I was updating my answer :), the lack of parentheses cause the undefined symbol error in the provided sample code because the pre-processor will not try to expand it as it does not match any defined non function-like macros.

Comment: @luk32 I see we though pretty much about the same in parallel. I also reworked my answer around `gcc -E` and got same results.

Comment: I am sorry. I had missed the spaces earlier. Have corrected the same. What I infer from your answer is that a macro is substituted for only
once. But consider the following case:
#define X (4+Z)

#define Z 2

int main()
{
printf("%d",X);
}

now according to you, the macro expands to 4+Z and should not substitute further and should also give error. But it works fine on my compiler. How would you explain this?

Comment: Because it will successfully resolve `Z` to `2`, which does not use the `X` macro. Each macro and any macros it uses will only be expanded once.

Answer (score 1):

You miss spaces

```
#define X (4+Y)
#define Y (X+3)
```

Comment: Not sure why this is being downvoted - this does address an issue with the code

Comment: @DrewMcGowen: I'm not downvoter, but this answer only points out one problem (and it's arguably not the biggest/main/most important problem in the code). Nor does it explain the significance of the space. I kinda see it as pointing out someone is missing a foot when they're missing a whole leg. It's not a *bad* answer, but it could certainly be improved.

Comment: This is getting downvoted because it does not even attempt to answer the question of `Can someone please explain the output?`. It is pretty clear that the example code provided is a sample with a simple typo that was never compile tested.

Comment: I accept, its not a complete answer. But when other answers started appearing I stopped editing as I was about to stat the same answer. Leaving the answer untouched.